# use of Window Shell in programme

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone tell me that if there is any harm (to OS(Win Xp) if i programme using window shell in ASP.NET.

Comment: What do you intend to run in this shell?

Comment: Harm? What kind of harm do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

**If you pass parametres to this** windows shell that get from your page and page parametres that a user can set, **then maybe a lucky attacker can make a big mess**, deleting files (maybe ?)

This is the Process class that run the apps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

If you use it for your backoffice and trusted users or you do not pass any parametres then is better. I use it that way for my trusted user to run an old application for my client that need to process some data and there was no other way for the time...